# Retrieve keys of output dictionary of python function without calling the function

Tags: python

assuming I have the following simple function

```
def f(name: str):
    print (name) 
    return {'x': 2, 'y': 1}
```

Assuming I have access to the function `f` and I want to retrieve the keys of the returned value dict, **without calling the function itself**, is there a way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**
The expected output in this case is: `['x', 'y']`

Comment: Yes, but you probably shouldn't use it. Is there a practical problem you are trying to solve this way?

Comment: What's the expected output in this case?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The problem is complex to explain here. What I provided is just a simple example that illustrates the end goal. Basically, I want to automate classes generation, where one method of the class will call `f` and the other needs to know the list of names of the ouput at compile time

Comment: @PCM ['x', 'y']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not annotate the return type, using a [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict):

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class F(TypedDict):
    x: int
    y: int


def f(name: str) -> F:
    print (name) 
    return {'x': 2, 'y': 1}
```

Not only does this make it easy to get the keys in the return dictionary from *outside* the function:

```
>>> f.__annotations__['return'].__annotations__.keys()
dict_keys(['x', 'y'])
```

it actually allows the type to be *checked*, both inside:

```py
def f(name: str) -> F:
    return {'x': 2, 'y': 1}  # OK


def g(name: str) -> F:
    return {'x': 2, 'y': '1'}  # wrong type


def h(name: str) -> F:
    return {'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 'foo'}  # extra key
```

and outside:

```py
x: int = f('foo')['x']  # OK
y: str = f('foo')['y']  # wrong type
z: int = f('foo')['z']  # missing key
```

the function (see [MyPy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=523c611e4341b44e03c2931fd3cf642f)). Otherwise the inferred return type is just `dict[str, int]`, which can't be checked so precisely, and you have to go spelunking into `f.__code__` to find the keys.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Fetch the values from `f.__code__.co_consts[-1]`.

```py
>>> f.__code__.co_consts[-1]
('x', 'y')
```

---

Literals are encoded in the code and constants of a function object. A convenient means to inspect this is to use [the builtin `dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html):

```py
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (name)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP

  3           8 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             12 LOAD_CONST               3 (('x', 'y'))
             14 BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP      2
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

As one can see, building a `dict` such as `{'x': a, 'y': b, ...}` will first load the individual values, then a single tuple of all keys. If nothing else is loaded before returning the dict, the keys are the last constant of the function.

[The code and constants of a function object is accessible for programmatic inspection.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) Fetching "the last constant of the function" `f` literally translates to `f.__code__.co_consts[-1]`.

---

Disclaimer: Extracting content from the code and constants of a function may be Python version dependent and especially depend on the function. Such an approach can be brittle and should not be used when arbitrary functions need to be processed.

Comment: While it does achieve what I want, I feel a bit unsafe as I am not really familiar with the `__code__` attribute, nor with what is happening in the background of `co_consts`. Also, your last comment __"Such an approach can be brittle ..."__ pushed me to go for the TypedDict approach. But Thanks (that was kool tbh )